# How to nicely manipulate environment variables via bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I want to add some helper commands to my shell. There are several commands I want to add, and they need to share some information between them. However, since I want a different state for each shell, I can't use files to store the shared information, but have to use environment variables.

This opens up the problem of setting environment variables: to change a variable in my shell and not only in a subprocess, I either need to put my commands in scripts and always source the scripts, or define them as functions and source the file via `.bashrc`.

I have also defined some auxiliary functions that are used by several of my commands, which I would prefer NOT to have in the scope of my main shell process.

I'm somewhat inexperienced with bash, so my question is: 
What is the cleanest way to implement this? Should I put my commands into scripts or into functions? Can I prevent my auxiliary functions from being sourced into the main shell? Is there an easier way to manipulate environment variables?

Comment: Just as an idea, you _could_ also store them in files whose names include the shell's PID. Not saying it's better or worse without knowing your use case.

Comment: You are getting awful answers because your question is badly phrased. That you are "inexperienced with bash" appears to be the least of your problems. Do you understand that environment variables are inherited by child processes yet those processes cannot not modify the environment vars of their parent?

Comment: @KurtisRader Yes, I understand that, it's part of my problem. But the main problem is that I'm trying to do something which bash is not supposed to do, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can store put your environment variables inside shell file (`myEnv.sh`). then you can use

```
source myEnv.sh
```

to load your env variables according to your need.

you can also use inject this into your main shell scripts

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have .profile files instead of .sh files.
case1.profile , case2.profile and source them whenever needed. 
use any one of below method to source the files.

source ~/.case1.profile

or

. ~/.case1.profile